# Any hints on working RTTY split?

Tags: dx, rtty

I tried to work TX5S yesterday on RTTY yesterday. They were running split, which I haven't done before on RTTY. I use fldigi along with an IC-7300.

I tried two methods. First, using the "lock" feature on fldigi, and second, using the split feature on IC-7300. The fldigi "lock" method was easier to understand, but it has serious limitations (mainly the amount of split). So I think the method using split on my rig is the way to go.

It was quite an experience. I was not successful - I think I was operating correctly, but I have a modest station. Hopefully I will get another chance. ZD7Z says they will also be doing some RTTY.

So my question is whether anyone has any hints on working split on RTTY in pileups. I was sending my call sign 2 times (also tried 3 times) and I would send as soon at the DX operator sent "UP" which seemed to be a substitute for "QRZ". Sometimes the DX operator would take a long time to respond, and I wondered whether I should send my call again a couple times.

I saw the pouncers up anywhere from about 1 to 5 kHz. I wasn't sure if there are issues with working just 1 kHZ up. I think there were more 4-5 kHz up.

BTW, I got a chuckle out of "LIDS UP UP UP UP" which the DX operator (or someone on their frequency) would occasionally transmit. We were also told to "spread out" which is a little tricky, especially with skip zone - you can only avoid the stations you can hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure for working split with RTTY is not fundamentally different from other modes. Sending one's call 3 times in a row is fairly normal; we have to allow for the DX operator re-tuning their VFO for picking out the mark / space signal of a new caller. This either happens with the DX operator turning a knob or clicking into their waterfall display. In any case, sending one's call just once may be too brief for the DX operator to identify it for tuning / clicking and getting a complete decode. As long as the DX operator does not respond to anyone, it is fine to repeat one's call again. As always, common courtesy requires to stop calling once the DX operator responds to someone else.

Comment: I was wondering that if the DX operator doesn't respond right away, that it means they got nothing and are more-or-less starting over. What I don't want to do is transmit too long and possibly miss the response.

I also wonder what kind of RTTY decoder they typically use, and whether they can decode all RTTY signals in the audio band in parallel.

Comment: It is difficult to address what you are wondering about if you do not mention it in your question.

Comment: There is no "starting over". A DX operator will continue to listen until he / his RTTY decoder picks out a complete callsign. When this takes longer than expected the issue is usually not that "they got nothing" but rather that they "got too much". It is best practise, of course, to keep transmissions short in order not to miss a reply. In practise, though, overlap happens sometimes. At least with a split rx/tx freq. it is less of a nuisance to others; and the DX op will start his reply as soon as he picked out a complete callsign, he is not going to wait until everyone finishes calling.